# How are real-time speed and torque of a brushless DC motor computed?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, torque, speed

Let's suppose I need to work with a three-phase brushless DC motor. The DC motor has only three wires to control its 3 phases, there is no other wires (no Hall effect sensor return for example). Usually one uses a driver (like an ESC) to control the speed of the motor: the MCU sends a PWM signal to the driver which in return controls the 3 phases of the motor.

I know that controlling the duty cycle controls the speed of the motor. But are drivers capable of computing the real-time speed (in rpm) of the motor when the motor does not have feedback wires? If so, how do they do?

Can they compute the real-time torque as well?

Comment: You might want to read up on *BLDC Sensorless control*. For example here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/sensorless-brushless-dc-bldc-motor-control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically back EMF sensing is used to commutate and get speed information for sensorless drive schemes.

You can read about it in [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/controlling-sensorless-bldc-motors-via-back-emf) article.

It doesn't work well at no or low RPMs so for startup the motor can be driven open loop, or a salient pole permanent magnet machine can use inductance saturation sensing to position the rotor and start commutation.

You can read about that from the following reference:

[A. CASSAT and L. CARDOLETTI, “closed-loop control of a brushless dc motor from standstill to medium speed,”](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5117165A/en?q=closed-loop%20control%20of%20brushless%20dc%20motor%20standstill%20medium%20speed&inventor=alain%20cassat&oq=closed-loop%20control%20of%20a%20brushless%20dc%20motor%20from%20standstill%20to%20medium%20speed%20alain%20cassat) US patent 51 17465, 1992.

For torque estimation the motor current is often good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The best control of 3 phase Delta Sensorless BLDC technology is very mature now with Field Oriented Control (FOC BLDC) Infineon is one source of such a solution with an ARM based SOC, system on a chip. THe current is sensed , harmonics filtered without fundamental phase shift , digitized and transformed from 3D to a rotating 2D vector space as torque can only be used with positive currents in 2 rotating phase currents.

The 3D to 2D is called the Clarke Transform following by the rotating 2D vectors called the Park Transform.

- actual flux is thus computed and expected vs actual are compared with input controls for full range frequency control with V/f controls normal for variable speed and current regulated with PWM to match the desired rotating flux.

There is also a feedback loop for comparing the rotating 2D currents with a PI controls for frequency and phase.

[image][image]

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE987x-Sensorless-Field-Oriented-Control-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf

TI, Allegro and many others also have various solutions for FOC.